# createOrderFromQuote() function not working

Tags: magento-1.8, forms

What is wrong with my createOrderFromQuote() function??

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->_objectId = 'id';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'quotation';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_quotation';

    $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('quotation')->__('Save Quote'));
    $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('quotation')->__('Delete Quote'));

    $this->_addButton('saveandcontinue', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save And Continue Edit'),
        'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
        'class'     => 'save',
    ), 1);

    $this->_addButton('createorder', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Create Order'),
        'onclick'   => 'createOrderFromQuote()',
        'class'     => 'add',
    ), 2);


    $this->_formScripts[] = "
        function toggleEditor() {
            if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('quotation_content') == null) {
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'quotation_content');
            } else {
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'quotation_content');
            }
        }

        function saveAndContinueEdit(){
            editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
        }

        function createOrderFromQuote(){

                var stored_cust_id_val = document.getElementById('quote_store_id').value;
                if(stored_cust_id_val == 0) {alert('You must load a customer or save this one before creating an order.'); return false;}
                if(confirm(\"You must save this quote before turning it into an order. Are you sure this quote has been saved since your last edit?\") == false) {return false;}
                var quote_id_val = " . $this->getRequest()->getParam("id") . ";

                new Ajax.Request(
                    createOrderFromQuoteURL,
                        {
                        method: 'get', // optional
                        parameters:{
                            'stored_cust_id' : stored_cust_id_val,
                            'quote_id' : quote_id_val
                            },
                        onComplete: function(cominBack)
                            {
                            if(cominBack.responseText != 0)
                                {
                                window.location.href = 'http://www.myeverydayvalue.com/index.php/ecorps/sales_order_create/index/customer_id/' + cominBack.responseText;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    );
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forgot to close the `_formScripts`.. please check second last line in below code.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->_objectId = 'id';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'quotation';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_quotation';

    $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('quotation')->__('Save Quote'));
    $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('quotation')->__('Delete Quote'));

    $this->_addButton('saveandcontinue', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save And Continue Edit'),
        'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
        'class'     => 'save',
    ), 1);

    $this->_addButton('createorder', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Create Order'),
        'onclick'   => 'createOrderFromQuote()',
        'class'     => 'add',
    ), 2);


    $this->_formScripts[] = "
        function toggleEditor() {
            if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('quotation_content') == null) {
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'quotation_content');
            } else {
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'quotation_content');
            }
        }

        function saveAndContinueEdit(){
            editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
        }

        function createOrderFromQuote(){

                var stored_cust_id_val = document.getElementById('quote_store_id').value;
                if(stored_cust_id_val == 0) {alert('You must load a customer or save this one before creating an order.'); return false;}
                if(confirm(\"You must save this quote before turning it into an order. Are you sure this quote has been saved since your last edit?\") == false) {return false;}
                var quote_id_val = " . $this->getRequest()->getParam("id") . ";

                new Ajax.Request(
                    createOrderFromQuoteURL,
                        {
                        method: 'get', // optional
                        parameters:{
                            'stored_cust_id' : stored_cust_id_val,
                            'quote_id' : quote_id_val
                            },
                        onComplete: function(cominBack)
                            {
                            if(cominBack.responseText != 0)
                                {
                                window.location.href = 'http://www.myeverydayvalue.com/index.php/ecorps/sales_order_create/index/customer_id/' + cominBack.responseText;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    );
        }
"; // add this
}
```

Comment: still cannot click the button sir